# hide unhide div tag

Tags: html, primefaces, show-hide

The following is the javascript code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function ShowHide(divId)
    {
        if(document.getElementById(divId).style.display == 'none')
        {
            document.getElementById(divId).style.display='block';
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the xhtml code to call the showhide function:

```
<p:column>
<p:commandLink onclick="javascript:ShowHide('HiddenDiv');" ajax="false" value="#{rail.trainNo}" action="#yardMaster.populateTrainDetails(rail.trainNo)}" style="font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;"></p:commandLink>
</p:column>
```

The above is the link which is supposed to unhide the following division:

```
<div style="display: none" id="HiddenDiv">
 Stuff
</div>
```

basically I'm trying to unhide a table in the div tag which is not displayed when the webpage is rendered for the first time. This is only half working, in the sense that when I click on the link it appears for a second or so and disappears immediately. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Have you looked at your question after posting? Please correct the indentation of your code, the p:commandLink is completely hidden.

Comment: ya I realised, just corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ajax="false"`. You don't need to refresh the entire page just the given div. In your case when you click on the `p:commandLink` the div will be displayed but since `ajax="false"` the whole page is refreshed - which will display your div in its initial state.

Comment: I cant really do that because the table is dynamic as well, depending on which row is clicked the table must change. <p:commandLink> is actually inside <p:column> tag which is part of the table, so these links are actually resiednt in cells of the table. Each link changes the table accordingly. Sorry my question was not clear enough. Is there any other way to do it without ajax="false"

Comment: `ajax="false"` in conjunction with ajax components is definitely not the way to go. `ajax="false"` reloads your entire page, without dynamic updates and this is not what you need. You can refresh the table through commandLink too, use `update="your_table_id"`

Comment: It gives the following error although I am giving the right address,
Cannot find component with identifier "HiddenDiv.subForm.trainTable" referenced from "j_idt18:mainTable:0:tableUpdater".

Comment: is your `update` target correct? make sure that it also includes the form id enclosing your dataTable (unless it has `prependId=false`), something like `update=":formAroundTheTable:yourTableId"`

Comment: yes that form id is the subForm in the error, and the HiddenDiv id the tag that surrounds the form.

Comment: It worked, silly mistake I had used '.' instead of ':' between subForm and HiddenDiv